# How to separate data with a comma

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

For example, I'm having a two set of vars with data type of string:

```
 users = "Admin, Staff"
 pass = "202cb9, caf1a"
```

These are vars with only normal string data type. The two vars above is generated, so I could only get these kind of data. The question is: 
How can I separate those data by the commas (like Admin -> 202cb9, Staff -> caf1a) and then store them into an array.

```
users_array(0) = "Admin"
users_array(1) = "Staff"
pass_array(0) = "202cb9"
pass_array(1) = "caf1a"
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two options to solve this problem:

```
    Dim users_array() As String = users.Split(New String() {", "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

and:

```
    Dim pass_array() As String = Split(users, ", ")
```

IMO, it is better to use `,<space>` as a separator string instead of just `,`, to avoid getting `<space>staff` at index 1.

Here the first solution works for both C# and VB.Net and second one is specific to VB.Net.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `users.Split(New Char() {","c})` as in this link.

http://www.dotnetperls.com/split-vbnet

Answer (score 1):

User `String.Split` to break strings apart on a specific character.  It returns an array.